# Installing Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS on Samsung series 5

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, samsung

I want to install Ubuntu Linux 12.04.4 LTS on my samsung NP300-E5X-S02IN laptop but I have heard a lot about the bricking problems in samsung laptops (probably because of problems in UEFI boot system). I already have Windows 7 installed but I also want to install Ubuntu alongside.

Could you tell me the safest possible method to install Ubuntu along with windows?
I have some knowledge about the installation process.

Comment: Can you disable Secure Boot in the BIOS Setup menu? A way **not** to do it is using Wubi.

Comment: Secure Boot has very little to do with the bricking problem. In theory, Ubuntu 12.04.4 should install fine with Secure Boot enabled, although in practice there can be problems on some computers or in some circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

The bricking problem has been bypassed with recent kernels, which 12.04.4 should provide. (You might want to wait 3 days until 14.04 LTS is released, though; it will have more up-to-date EFI support generally.)

Comment: Do read question https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage/+bug/1040557  .  Update your firmware if necessary.  Still seems risky to me, with not enough NVRAM.

Comment: Note the date of the bug to which you linked, and the fact that the Status Summary box at the top is filled with "Fix Released" links. As you might guess from the words "Fix Released," that means that a fix has been released.